# "Python: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes...: malformed \N character escape" when I'm trying to type an input statement

Tags: python

```
def option3():
    copy("EMPLOYEE.DAT", "EMPLOYEE.DAT.bak")
    oldfile = open("EMPLOYEE.DAT.bak")
    newfile = open("EMPLOYEE.DAT", "w")
    data = oldfile.readlines()
    empdict = {}
    for line in data:
        ID, Name, Number, empType = line.split('|')
        empType = empType.rstrip('\n')
        empdict[ID] = [Name, Number, empType]
    requested_ID = input("Enter the ID you want to modify: ")
    for each_ID in empdict:
        if each_ID == requested_ID:
            print("Requested Employee Data:\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(each_ID, empdict[each_ID][0], empdict[each_ID][1], empdict[each_ID][2]))
            correct_data = input("Is this the correct employee data [Y\N]: ")
            if correct_data == 'Y':
                pass
```

I was creating a program to store employee-related data. as a mini project. However as I tried to run my (barely-completed program_ I get the unicode error message and Python highlights the parenthesis after `input`. I've googled for answers but it seems like the common issue is related to file paths which I am not dealing with here.

This is just a section of the entire code and if needed I will edit this post and post it here.

Also when I tried to run it by double clicking the file the command prompt just shuts down immediately, but if I remove             `correct_data = input("Is this the correct employee data [Y\N]: ")` then it works normally.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Either replace `\` with `/`, i.e.:

```
correct_data = input("Is this the correct employee data [Y/N]: ")
```

or escape `\` by replacing it with `\\`, i.e.

```
correct_data = input("Is this the correct employee data [Y\\N]: ")
```

or use a raw string:

```
correct_data = input(r"Is this the correct employee data [Y\N]: ")
```

For more details see [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) from the documentation.